# writing on hard disk on ubuntu

Tags: permissions, hard-drive

I am not able to write on my hard disk ( eg- I am not even able to create a new folder there). In the properties it is written that the owner is root and it has not given writing rights to other users.
We cant login as root in ubuntu.

[this is how my hard disk is shown in files , as "Computer" in other locations options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaDep.png)

[this is what i see when i open hard disk i.e. click on "Computer" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBQBu.png)

But every permission is given to root and I cant write or edit.
How can I get the permission to write in the hard disk and if I want to access files in hard disk, what would be the address of files ???

Comment: Are you expecting it to work like on Windows where anyone can write to the root of the C drive? Linux doesn't work like that. Only the root user can write to the root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not Windows, where any user can write into System Dir by just clicking 'Yes' on UAC Prompt.

To access system files and folders as RW, type on terminal or ALT+F2 `sudo filemanager /`, here I see you're using nautilus, so type

`sudo nautilus /` -> Enter Password -> Access / files.

To access other files or volume on your computer, click on 'Other Locations' and see if your volume are listed there and if not, type `sudo fdisk -l` to know volume information. and mount it accordingly.

**Note :** `gksu` is recommended over `sudo` for running GUI applications due to various of factors, however it's removed in latest version of Debian/Ubuntu. In that case use pkexec or gvfs admin backend.

Comment: Note that [it's not a good idea to run graphical apps with `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/q/270006/301745). `gksudo`/`gksu` is probably the best alternative.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the fact, but now gksu is deprecated. It is removed from Debian, Ubuntu 18.04 and other newer Linux distribution version. However, I'll edit my answer for a better span. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I guess I'm behind the times. What's the best option now, `pkexec`?

Comment: @wjandrea yes, pkexec is what we have now. ^^Also read my updated answer.

Comment: Here's a little basics about gvfs admin backend : https://itsfoss.com/gksu-replacement-ubuntu/

For pkexec, I couldn't found any better information than `man pkexec`.